# Re-Attaching a DCOS agent node to DCOS

Tags: centos, marathon, dcos

We have a DCOS 1.9.0 cluster set up with 11 public agent nodes ( CentOS ). However sometime in the last couple of days one of the agent nodes got detached and it is not available in the DCOS UI.

I'm able to ssh and access the agent node which has been detached. Is there any way to re-attach this instance without any data loss. Please can you suggest the best way to debug this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We were able to fix the problem by following the instructions in this link : https://dcos.io/docs/1.9/administering-clusters/update-a-node/ within this sub-section : Updating nodes by manually killing agents